# How to select certain fields with mongodb doctrine in symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to find some documents from my mongo Database, and I'm using the function : FindBy()
unfortunately this function doesn't have any field selection arguments like native mongodb driver has with the function : find().
Does any one know how to select custom fields in the doctrine of Mongodb ?
Thanks

Comment: which one you are using, doctrine ORM or doctrine ODM? for mongodb you need to use ODM. findBy custom field is same as ORM

Comment: ODM is a reasonable assumption given the tags "doctrine" and "mongodb" plus the phrase "I'm using the function : FindBy()" which indicates basic success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use QueryBuilder with the `select` operator:

```
$result = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')->select('field1', 'field2')->field('field3')->equals('somevalue')->getQuery()->execute();
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! User should be the name of the collection right ?

Comment: @Sekai Correct. Using Symfony you'll probably refer to the repository as `SomeBundle:SomeDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dynamically want to select fields, use the field name as an array.

```
$selects = ['field1','field2','field3'];  // you can pass through api or else
$result = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Collection')->select($selects)->getQuery()->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

findBy does support operators, but the argument provided should be an array with the field name as key for the first dimension, like so :

```
$results = $yourRepositoryInstance->findBy(['somefield' => ['$in' => $arrayOfValues]]);
```